# Grails 3.0 application.yml configuration for hyphenated URLs

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

How do you configure hyphenated URLs in the new Grails 3.0 `application.yml` file?

The following configuration does not seem to be sticking:

**grails-app/config/application.yml**

```
grails:
   web:
      url:
         converter: "hyphenated"
```

My test controller is:

**grails-app/controllers/BookAuthorsController.groovy**

```
class BookAuthorsController {

   def index() {
   }

}
```

And the view is at:
**grails-app/views/bookAuthors/index.gsp**

This page (with the undesirable camel case URL) displays OK:
http://localhost:8080/bookAuthors

This page should display but results in a *Page Not Found (404)* error:
http://localhost:8080/book-authors

Comment: For reference, the old `grails.web.url.converter = "hyphenated"` configuration is documented in the *Customizable URL Formats* section at:
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.0.x/guide/introduction.html#webFeatures

Comment: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues and we will get it straightened out.  Thanks.

Comment: Issue filed: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9017